# How to rewrite part of a line in a text file in C

Tags: c, delete-row

I am currently trying to create a program that allows a file full of names and marks to be modified and deleted. I currently can locate the name and find the target line, but I was wondering if there was a more effective way of allowing the line to be edited rather than just copying the line, making a new structure out of it, and allowing the user to change the particular values. If not I'm happy to go the long way, I was just hoping there is something more efficient

Comment: You cannot insert or delete bytes inside a file if that is the question. The simple way is to load the file in memory, edit there and save back (the whole file).

Comment: Read the file into memory, operate on the data in memory, write out a new file when done.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a bit can be done by skipping the undesired bytes, but there is no way to edit that part without memory allocation or copying. Here is a deletion example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
        char *content = "John\nMichael\nAndrew\n";
        char *target = strstr(content, "Michael");
        int len_bef_tag = target - content;
        int targlen = strchr(target, '\n') - target;
        char *ptr = content;

        /* deletion */
        fwrite(ptr, 1, len_bef_tag, stdout);
        ptr = target + targlen + 1;
        printf("%s", ptr);

        return 0;
}
```